# Ubuntu 10 Apache Virtual Hosts suddenly missing

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost

I have a bunch of apache virtual hosts set up on an Ubuntu machine.  They were working for a long time and now they're not:

```
$ a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/somesite.com 
ERROR: No site found matching /etc/apache2/sites-available/somesite.com!
```

What could I have done wrong?  This is happening for all virtual hosts on my machine.  They are all there under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` but apache doesn't seem to see them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `a2ensite somesite.com`.